# Gtk-Critical **: gtk_widget_show assertion GTK_IS_WIDGET(WIDGET)

Tags: c, windows, gtk

I'm getting started with Gtk+, I'm following this tutorial how to make first application, but when I try to run the executable, I get this error:

```
Gtk-Critical **: gtk_widget_show assertion GTK_IS_WIDGET(WIDGET)
```

I can see on google a lot of people with same error, but I can't see the reply with how to fix this..

My C Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkBuilder *builder;
GtkWidget *app;

G_MODULE_EXPORT
void on_app_destroy (void)
{
gtk_main_quit ();
}

G_MODULE_EXPORT
void on_menu_quit_activate (void)
{
gtk_main_quit ();
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
/* Initialize GTK+ */
g_log_set_handler ("Gtk", G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING, (GLogFunc) gtk_false, NULL);
gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
g_log_set_handler ("Gtk", G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING, g_log_default_handler, NULL);

builder = gtk_builder_new ();
gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "tut.glade", NULL);
app = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "app"));
gtk_builder_connect_signals (builder, NULL);

g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (builder));

/* Enter the main loop */
gtk_widget_show (app);
gtk_main ();
return 0;
}
```

glad file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<glade-interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 2.16 -->
  <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
  <widget class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <child>
      <widget class="GtkFixed" id="fixed1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <child>
          <widget class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="width_request">113</property>
            <property name="height_request">42</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </widget>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">149</property>
            <property name="y">69</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </widget>
    </child>
  </widget>
  <widget class="GtkWindow" id="window2">
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
  </widget>
</glade-interface>
```

compile options:

```
`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` -export-dynamic
```

Linker settings:

```
-export-dynamic
```

My IDE: Code::Blocks, compiler: GNUC C Compiler

How to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that there is no object whose id is `app` in your glade file. If you want to display the window, you have to pass the id associated with the window i.e. `window1`. Thus you code can be changed to:

```
app = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window1")); 
if (NULL == app)
{
    /* Print out the error. You can use GLib's message logging  */
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to file object with id \"window1\" \n");
    /* Your error handling code goes here */
}
```

There are few other suggestions:
1. It is better to use `GError **` parameter in `gtk_builder_add_from_file` call. So instead of just `gtk_builder_add_from_file` use the following piece of code for your reference:

```
GError *err = NULL; /* It is mandatory to initialize to NULL */
...
if(0 == gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "tut.glade", &err))
{
    /* Print out the error. You can use GLib's message logging */
    fprintf(stderr, "Error adding build from file. Error: %s\n", err->message);
    /* Your error handling code goes here */
}
...
```

2. From your glade file, the root element `glade-interface` indicates that you are using `libglade` format for saving you glade file instead of `GtkBuilder` format. Thus you may need to link `libglade` in the build. But from the glade file you are indicating that Gtk version is 2.16 or above, you may need to use `GtkBuilder` format. In that case you will need to convert to `GtkBuilder` format which can be done using [`gtk-builder-convert`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/gtk-builder-convert.html) script or opening the glade file in Glade application & saving in the `GtkBuilder` format (This option will depend on your Glade version).
Hope this helps!